# Why are there no rightabove / leftbelow commands?

Tags: split

Referring to the existing [leftabove](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:lefta) and [rightbelow](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bel) commands, which do the following:

- execute a command
- if the command results in a split, it will be either opened on the left, or above the current window for `leftabove` (and analogously for `rightbelow`).

Question is: why don't the counterparts `rightabove` and `leftbelow` exist?
Wouldn't it be logical that I want my new split either on the right, or above? (Or either on the left or below?)

**Addendum:** I understand the wording of my question *("I want my new split either on the right, or above")* might have been misleading. Let me try to make the question more clear.

`leftabove` means: if you encounter a `vsplit` then the new window should be on the **left**; if you encounter a `split`, then the new window should be **above**.

`rightbelow` means: if you encounter a `vsplit` then the new window should be on the **right**; if you encounter a `split`, then the new window should be **below**.

*So what I'm asking is, why don't we have these two?*

`leftbelow` means: if you encounter a `vsplit` then the new window should be on the **left**; if you encounter a `split`, then the new window should be **below**.

`rightabove` means: if you encounter a `vsplit` then the new window should be on the **right**; if you encounter a `split`, then the new window should be **above**.

Answer (score 3):

> Wouldn't it be logical that I want my new split either on the right, or above?

You never want your new split to be either on the right or above.

You either want your new split to be on the right, in which case you can use `:rightbelow`; or you want it above, in which case you can use `:leftabove`.

Maybe it would have been less confusing for the user if Vim had provided 4 distinct modifiers:

```
:splitabove
:splitbottom
:splitleft
:splitright
```

Although, Vim would have had to deal with possible nonsensical combinations, like:

```
:splitabove vsplit
:splitright split
```

Anyway, instead, it was chosen to provide only 2 modifiers, merging `:splitabove` and `:splitleft` into `:leftabove`; and merging `:splitbottom` and `:splitright` into `:rightbelow`.   *The command* to which you apply the modifier will choose which part of the modifier to honor.  For example, `:split` will honor the `above` part of `:leftabove`, while `:vsplit` will honor the `left` part.  *You* have no control over which part is honored; the command following the modifier does.

Comment: Thanks, this was also my understanding, but it does not answer my question. I'll try to reword it a bit.

Comment: With "either to the right or above" I meant something like: I want `vsplit` to go to the *right* and any `split` to go *above*. See addendum to the question.

Comment: I don't know.  All I can say is that I've never been in a situation where I felt I was missing `leftbelow` or `rightabove`, because I always know how a command is going to split the window (horizontally vs vertically).  I could see how they are needed if there were some commands whose splitting direction was computed at runtime; but I can't think of any.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand what you are saying. Basically when you call `:rightbelow`, you know in advance that you will only use the `right` part of it.

Comment: I thought about the question before reading the answer or these comments. FWIW the "you know ahead of time" idea is exactly how I would have described it, too. Perhaps, the answer can be modified to emphasize this and this one can be put to bed...